# Ansible playbook. Always quote template expression brackets when hey contain a value

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I am getting error running this ansible playbook. It simply tries to load from ansible facts, an attribute (the size) of a specific mount by looking in mount_points within ansible facts. (i) My variable expression is quoted wrongly somehow, have tried a few permutations of brackets and quotes. (ii) Once I take care of fixing the quoting, would the underlying command actually find the and extract the required fact attribute into my variable `mountsize`?

```
- hosts: target_hosts
  vars:
    mountsize: "999"
  tasks: 
    - name: Collect only facts returned by facter
      setup:
        fact_path : "/etc/ansible/facts.d"

    - debug: 
        var: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_mounts' | selectattr('mount', 'equalto', '/apps') | map(attribute='size_total') | "{{mountsize}}"] }}"
```

Expected example output of mountsize in bytes:
234567891012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code, including your use of braces (`{{ }}`), the way you are referencing ansible_facts, and the way you are attempting to assign a value to the `mountsize` variable

Try:

```
    - set_fact:
        mountsize: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount', 'equalto', '/apps') | map(attribute='size_total') | first }}"

    - debug:
        var: mountsize
```